# In the Parse.com iOS SDK, how do you make sure that Parse forgets about a user once they're logged out?

Tags: parse-platform

If you follow the [Facebook integration tutorial on Parse](https://parse.com/tutorials/integrating-facebook-in-ios) you'll see that they'll tell you to use the following method:

```
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:
     ^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) { ... }];
```

I've handled users just fine this way for a very long time. Every time I log out and invoke the method again, it transitions to the Facebook application and a potentially different user is expected to log in.

But recently, after I logged into Facebook in iOS, I noticed something strange.

Let's say a user `Ralf` has logged into the application through the above mechanism. Then, he logs out again:

```
[PFUser logOut];
```

This will show the log-in screen. This is a simple screen with a single button that triggers the login method as stated above.

This time, instead of showing the Facebook application to prompt, `Ralf` gets AUTOMATICALLY logged in again. i.e. his `PFUser` instance has been retained and now gets passed straight into the login block.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can unlink a PFUser from either Facebook or Twitter by using PFFacebookUtils's and PFTwitterUtils's unlink methods.

```
if([PFFacebookUtils isLinkedWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]]){

            [PFFacebookUtils unlinkUserInBackground:[PFUser currentUser] block:^(BOOL Success,NSError *unlinkError){
                if(!unlinkError){
                    // User unlinked
                }else{
                   // Erro while unlink user
                }
            }];
        }
```

Comment: Hmmm. I wasn't looking to disassociate the user's Facebook profile. I'm wondering why `logInWithPermissions:block:` seems to be stateful: it automatically knows what user to log in as if they've already logged in before.

I expect `logInWithPermissions:block:` to totally forget who was logged in do the whole oauth dance again for a new user.

Comment: Calling logout on the FB session invalidates the session token, but that token may be shared across multiple clients.